# Replacing on third match

Tags: php, regex

In this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/(\s*)@(if|foreach)(\s*\(.*\))/';
```

How can I replace every # with $ on (\s*(.*))

This will be used afterwards:

```
preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php $2$3: ?>', $value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

There you can define an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that returns the replacement, where you would be able to perform your additional task on group 3 and then build the replacement as you need.

From the example in the second link

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
?>
```

You can see that you can access the group 3 like this: `$match[3]`

Comment: How will I be able to access $3 or $2? Here's what I have:  preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($match) {
   return "???";
  }, $value);

Comment: @oaziz I updated my answer with content from the second link.